# Open a URL when click on ImageView on Android

Tags: java, android

I get the following error below

`startActivity (android.content.intent) in activity cannot be applied to (intent)`

For this code - I have tried many different things - is there anything I need to add to the manifest? Thank you so much for your help!

```
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Fb);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           intent browserintent = new intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("www.yahoo.com"));
            startActivity(browserintent);

        }
    }
```

Comment: The SDK `Intent` class starts with an uppercase `I`. Did you somehow get your IDE to auto-generate a lowercase-`i` `intent` class in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com"));
 startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a scheme `http` or `https` in your `Uri`:

```
 Intent browserintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com"));
        startActivity(browserintent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com"));      
    startActivity(intent);
```